# Is preg_split a 1:1 replacement for this specific case of using split()?

Tags: php

I am converting an old legacy code to a more modern PHP version.

today's task is converting split().

In 99% of specific use cases, I converted into a simple explode(), because we were using a normal string and not a regex

But what about this case ?

```
$ips = split ("\.", "$IPaddress");
```

Should I convert into a `preg_split` ?

```
$ips = preg_split ("/\./", "$IPaddress");
```

*Note: I converted `\.` into a regexp `/\./`*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your `preg_split` would be equivalent.  However, you can also use `explode()` here as well.  The `.` is a special character in regex and so the pattern needs escaping hence the `\`.

You could just change it to `$ips = explode(".", "$IPaddress");`